# Accessing virtual base class function from a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

1.In the main function below, why does `d.foo(9.5)` not select the `Base::foo(double)` method from the base class? Doesn't the derived class inherit that method?

2.What causes the compile error?

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void foo(int){
        cout << "Base::foo(int)" << endl;
    }
    virtual void foo(double){
        cout << "Base::foo(double)" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void foo(int){
        cout << "Derived::foo(int)" << endl;
    }
};

void main() {
    Derived d;
    Base b, *pb = &d;

    d.foo(9);     // selects Derived::foo(int)         
    d.foo(9.5);   // selects Derived::foo(int)         
    pb->foo(9);   // selects Derived::foo(int) 
    pb->foo(9.5); // selects Base::foo(double)  

    Derived * d; 
    d->foo(9);    // compile error
}
```

Comment: Read wikipage on [virtual method tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) i.e. vtables.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Virtual dispatch explains all the results except the one that's being asked about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compilation error is because of two variables with the same name in `main()`.

As to your problem with inherited functions not being called for an instance of your `Derived` (except via pointer to `Base`)

The standard describes the "hiding rule", which makes this happen.   Essentially, member functions declared in derived classes hide inherited functions with the same name but different signature inherited from the base class.    The hiding rule is independent of whether the inherited functions are virtual or not.

The common solution is to introduce all inherited functions from the base class with `using Base::foo`.    For example,

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void foo(int){
        cout << "Base::foo(int)" << endl;
    }
    virtual void foo(double){
        cout << "Base::foo(double)" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    using Base::foo;
    virtual void foo(int){
        cout << "Derived::foo(int)" << endl;
    }
};
```

Another solution is to remember to explicitly override all inherited versions of the function (implement the derived class version to simply call the base class version of each function).   This works with older compilers that do not support a `using` directive like the above.   The catch is that it is necessary to explicitly do this with every inherited overload, and it is easy to miss one.

Answer (score 3):

> In the main function below, why does `d.foo(9.5)` not select the `Base::foo(double)` method from the base class? Doesn't the derived class inherit that method?

Yes, but it's hidden by the function with the same name in the derived class. You can unhide it with a using-declaration in the derived class:

```
using Base::foo;
```

> What causes the compile error?

You're trying to declare a second variable called `d`. Change the name to something that's not already used; and initialise it to point to a valid object, otherwise you'll have a runtime error or other undefined behaviour.

```
Derived * pd = &d; 
pd->foo(9);    // selects Derived::foo(int)
```

Also, `main` has the wrong return type. It must return `int`.

Answer (score 2):

1) Because this is exactly how polymorphism work. If a virtual function is redefined in a derived class, this (and only this) redefined version will be called. If the function is not `virtual` it's vice versa: only the base class function will be called.

```
//Example 1: non-virtual function
class Base
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Base";
    }
}

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived";
    }
}

Base * base = new Base();
base->foo()//prints "Base"
Base * derived = new Derived();
derived->foo()//prints "Base", since the function is not virtual, and the version from the base class is called


//Example 2: virtual function
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Base";
    }
}

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived";
    }
}

Base * base = new Base();
base->foo()//prints "Base"
Base * derived = new Derived();
derived->foo()//prints "Derived", since the function is virtual, and the redefined version from Derived class is called
```

2) The compile error happens because you have a conflicting declaration - two objects are called `d`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Derived * d; 
  d->foo(9);    // compile error
```

You don't have instantiated the object:

Derived * d = new Derived;

If you not create the object the compiler use the previous declaration of d: Derived d that is not a pointer.